# How to use Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, urlencode

I have a piece of HTML Code, which offers you to put your email in an input field after hitting a button (after clicking the button the textfield appears):

```
<div class="column-left w-col w-col-5">
<label class="radio-button-field-2 left w-radio">
<input type="radio" id="paypal" name="payout" value="paypal" data-name="payout" required="" class="w-form-formradioinput radio-button w-radio-input">
<span for="paypal" class="radio-button-label-2 w-form-label">PayPal-Konto</span>
</label>
</div>

<div class="block-payout-paypal" style="">
<input type="email" class="text-field-2 w-input" maxlength="256" name="paypal-email-2" data-name="Paypal Email 2" placeholder="max.moritz@beispiel.com" id="paypal-email" required="">
</div>
```

My Goal now is to write a script which allows me to click on the button  and then file out the input field. The website is: https://gruenkraft-zufriedenheit.de/      And the button I'm looking for is called: PayPal-Konto

Comment: Read Documentation here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When (PayPal-Konto) button is clicked, you would see a input, you can locate that with the help of below code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://gruenkraft-zufriedenheit.de/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='PayPal-Konto']"))).click()#ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='PayPal-Konto']")))).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='paypal-email-2']"))).send_keys('some-email@gmail.com')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer? But why do I have to scroll? The checkbox did work in my Python Code without scrolling?!

Comment: oh well, yes you are right. When I did maually, I had to scroll down so I thought automation would also expect us to scroll, but it works without scroll. Updated the code as well. see above, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Hey, I´m coding with Selenium just for 2 days. What would I have to delete? And how is your code actually working? I first thought that I hava to click on the radio button and then the input filed would appear. That didn´t work with my code.  Why is that so and how is your nice code solving that?

Comment: Please just tell me how it works. First you seem to wait until the element has loaded then you´re clicking and after the input field loaded you typ in?! But why do I have to wait? Is that because of the stylesheet?

Comment: yes your understanding is correct, for why do I have to wait? - for this, basically when we use explicit wait, it will try to find web element at an interval of 500 ms, until a specified time in the code. so I would say, it's more reliable then standard driver_find_element which won't wait and try to click immediately causing unstable scripting in Selenium

Comment: So you say that without explicit waiting, Selenium click´s before it found the element? That would mean that this code should work, because it waits 4s after findig the element to click? : element = driver.find_element_by_id("paypal")
time.sleep(4)
element.click()

Comment: But it isn´t working and says that this element isn´t clickable? How is the code on their website working, I thought that the input field would be there after you pushed the button?!

Comment: no I did not say that, with `drive.find_element_by_id` it would look for element immediately, if found return if not raise `no such element exception`, where as with explicit wait it would keep on trying if elements are not available immediately.

Comment: You can read more about explicit waits here at official site https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I think I wasn´t exact enough. Conclusion: If we would use the normale method for locating an element it could come to a wrong timing. I think my understanding problem was that I wrote a code: driver.find_element_by_id("paypal") ==> this is the code for the radio button which stand´s in Code about your span element: https://gruenkraft-zufriedenheit.de/  .

Comment: When I then told the programm to click, it told me than an other element would receive the click. Everything else about the timing you explained is clear for me now but why is the textfield under the buttons clicked when i write click radio button?

Comment: see that check box is not visible to me, and with my selector `//span[text()='PayPal-Konto']` it's basically looking for text, yes if website is not in English then this would fail, so we need a common selector, may be we can use this class name `span.radio-button-label-2.w-form-label`

Comment: Ah, but why is it reacting when clicking on span. Isn't it just the job of the radio button to handle a click?!

Comment: What I want to say is just: In your code the condition is, that the element has to be visible. So that will take a short time until it is "VISIBLE". But why doesn´t it work when I just say: time.wait(4) what is the same?! Please help me to clear my missunderstanding

Comment: So what means "is visible"?!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://gruenkraft-zufriedenheit.de/ ')
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button_tag_name_youre_looking_for')
element.click()
```

from then I use beautifulsoup to go on with what I needed to do

Hope this helps : )

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code too.

```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='PayPal-Konto']").click()
  driver.find_element_by_id("paypal-email").send_keys("text")
```

Updated as per comments.